# ios - trying to understand how cellForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath work when dealing with UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

With the help of the good people of StackOverflow, I have these two methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)
            reuseIdentifier:@"business"];

    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];

    NSLog(businessPrivacy);
    // FIND IF THE BUSINESS PLAN IS PRIVATE OR NOT.

        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f); 

        CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, MAX(size.height, 44.0f) + 20.0f)]; 
        label.numberOfLines = 0; 
        label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; 
        label.text = comment;  

        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];        

    return cell;
}

//Cell size for word wrapping.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{    
    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f); 

    CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height + (10 * 2);
}
```

The effect that they have is reducing font size from default font size, and dynamically resizing to ALMOST fit the entire text of a comment no matter how long that text might be.

What I am confused with is that I have some of the same code in both methods, and I dont know how it really should look like.  I do know both methods are getting called, but not sure what should be where so they would work properly.

Thanks in advance for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need them in both.  I have rewritten your code with comments so that you can make sense of it:

```
//This function is used to create the cell and the content of the cell.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    //Here you are allocating a new cell with a reuse identifier.  This is only needed if
    //you plan on reusing the cells and using [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier]
    //Reusable cells will save you some memory and make your tableview work more smoothly,
    //however here you are not selecting from the reusable pool, and are instead making a new cell each time
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyleDefault)
            reuseIdentifier:@"business"];

    //This is pulling the text for the comment, it is obviously necessary
    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];

    NSLog(businessPrivacy);
    // FIND IF THE BUSINESS PLAN IS PRIVATE OR NOT.

    // This is creating a constraint size for the label you are making
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f); 

    // This is determining the size that you will need for the label based on the comment
    // length and the contraint size
    CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

    //  Here you are creating your label and initializing it with the frame that you have
    //  determined by your size calculations above
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, MAX(size.height, 44.0f) + 20.0f)];

    // setting up the label properties
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap; 
    label.text = comment;  

    // adding the label view to the cell that you have created
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];        

    // return the cell for the table view
    return cell;
}

//Cell size for word wrapping.
//This method will determine how tall each row needs to be.
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    //Here you are getting the comment again.  This is necessary to determine how tall you need
    //the cell to be    
    NSString *comment = [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:(@"comment")];

    // Again you are getting the constraints because you are going to us this size
    // to constrain the height of the cell just like you determined the size for the label.
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320 - (10 * 2), 20000.0f); 

    // Again, determining the size that we will need for the label, because it will drive
    // the height of the cell
    CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap]; 

    //  Finally, we can determine the height for the cell!
    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    //  return the height, which is the height of the label plus some extra space to make
    //  it look good.
    return height + (10 * 2);
}
```

So basically, the `cellForRow...` function creates the content of the cell and the `heightForRow...` function determines the height.  You need all of that information in both of them because the `cell` function only creates the content of the cell while the `height` function creates the height of the row and the comment, constraint, and size are all important in determine the `label` size for the cell content and the height of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

So `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, as its name suggests, only deal with the height of the cells. i.e. the return value (a `CGFloat`) of that function is the height of the cell at the specified indexpath.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` on the other hand sets up the actual cell, including all its subviews. What happens is, say some cells have a 5-line `UILabel` and some have 1-line. Then You need to adjust the size of the cell in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, but at the same time you also need to adjust the size of the `UILabel` within the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The latter will not automatically happen. You need to take care of both yourself.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  So then I need to have that code in both places?  In my case, what is the subview supposed to be? I just have text that I need to display in each cell.  Should the text be the subview? Or a main view?

Comment: Yes. Your text is in a `UILabel`, and you are setting it up in `UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, MAX(size.height, 44.0f) + 20.0f)];`. This code adjusts the size of your label. And in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, you adjust the size of the cell itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to write the same code two or more times, you should consider extracting the duplicate code into a method or function.  But you have some other problems we should address.

Let's declare some constants so we don't have to repeat numbers all over the code:

```
static const CGFloat kLabelMargin = 10.0f;
static const CGFloat kLabelWidth = 320.0f - 2.0f * kLabelMargin;
```

One line you have duplicated in both methods looks up the comment for a row.  Let's make a method to do that:

```
- (NSString *)commentForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [[items_array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"comment"];
}
```

The other duplicated code computes the height of the row, so let's make a function to return that:

```
static CGFloat heightForComment(NSString *comment) {
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(kLabelWidth, 20000.0f);
    CGSize size = [comment sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return MAX(size.height, 44.0f) + 2.0f * kLabelMargin;
}
```

Now we can rewrite your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return heightForComment([self commentForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]);
}
```

Finally, let's rewrite your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  We will make it properly reuse cells (to avoid wasting memory), and we'll make it use the new method and function we created.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *const kReuseIdentifier = @"business";
    static const NSInteger kLabelTag = 1;

    NSLog(@"%@", businessPrivacy);
    // FIND IF THE BUSINESS PLAN IS PRIVATE OR NOT.

    NSString *comment = [self commentForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, kLabelWidth, heightForComment(comment));

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kReuseIdentifier];
    UILabel *label;
    if (cell) {
        label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kLabelTag];
        label.frame = labelFrame;
    } else {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kReuseIdentifier];
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        label.tag = kLabelTag;
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    }

    label.text = comment;

    return cell;
}
```